# Fermi energy on a "fermion pre-gas model"

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, definition

I'm having serious trouble while trying to follow an example from Callen's "Thermodynamics and an introduction to Thermostatistics" regarding the definition of the Fermi energy.

In said example one has a spin 1/2 fermion system with three spatial orbits with energies $\epsilon_1$, $\epsilon_2$, $\epsilon_3$ and each state can be empty or occupied, taking into account that the occupied state is 2-degenerate due to the spin. The mean number of particles in the system is found to be

$$
\bar{N}=\frac{2}{e^{\beta(\epsilon_1-\mu)}+1}+\frac{2}{e^{\beta(\epsilon_2-\mu)}+1}+\frac{2}{e^{\beta(\epsilon_3-\mu)}+1}
$$

So far so good. But then the example goes on, stating that:

- If we have four fermions and $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2$, the Fermi level must lie somewhere between $\epsilon_2$ and $\epsilon_3$.
- If we have four fermions and $\epsilon_1<\epsilon_2=\epsilon_3$, the Fermi level coincides with $\epsilon_2$.
- If we have two fermions and $\epsilon_1<\epsilon_2=\epsilon_3$, the Fermi level lies between $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2(=\epsilon_3)$.

I don't understand these statements. Doesn't the Fermi energy coincide with the highest occupied energy level at zero temperature? I would say that in the first case $\epsilon_F=\epsilon_1$ since all the fermions fill the lowest energy levels, leaving the $\epsilon_3$-level empty; and that $\epsilon_F=\epsilon_1$ in the third.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fermi energy is such that all states with a energy same or lower are occupied at zero temperature. You have gaps in the spectrum leading to a wider range of "possible" fermi levels. Take the first case (assuming e_3>e_2=e_1): at zero temperature the states e_1 and e_2 are occupied and e_3 is not. Meaning e_f must not be smaller than e_1,e_2 and must be smaller that e_3. The third case is the same practically. In the second case the upper and lower limit coincide making e_f unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for answering! But I still don't get it. You said that the Fermi energy is such that all states with a energy same or lower are occupied. In the first case, for example, there are no fermions on any level above $\epsilon_2$. Why should the Fermi energy be there, since all levels above that are empty?

Comment: lets say e_1=e_2=0 and e_3=1. Then for this discrete system it doesnt make any difference, whether you say e_f=0.5 or e_f=0.0001 or e_f =0.9999, because there arent any states in between. it is a simple ambiguity due to the discrete nature of this system